# How to inline-align cards images when above and bottom texts are of any length?

Tags: css

[image]

I'm trying to create a layout without using JavaScript, just like picture attached,
top and bottom are text and middle is image, What should I do to make images inline align to each other without using JavaScript and grid. also top and bottom text are dynamic can be of any length.

Comment: You can take a look over [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma722/pxmk2rjh/12/)

Comment: Just to be sure: When you request without using grid, you mean css display:grid ?

Comment: yes with out using css display: grid and also no javascript.

Comment: As far as I know, your only posibilities then are flexbox (as in Roberrt answer) or table. Any one will force to group the content by rows .

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }
.containers {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eee;
}

main > img {
  margin-top: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Align Image inline</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="containers">
      <div class="container">
        <header>Header Header Header Header Header Header
        Header Header Header Header Header Header
        Header Header Header Header Header Header</header>
        <main>
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="" />
        </main>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <header>Header</header>
        <main>
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="" />
        </main>
        <footer>Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer </footer>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <header>Header</header>
        <main>
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="" />
        </main>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add css to add `ellipsis` if the header is more than 3 lines

https://jsfiddle.net/q6herk2c/4/`888`

Comment: You can take a look over [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma722/pxmk2rjh/12/) no `ellipsis` and no fixed height for header and footer.

Comment: @knightMove But not that what the asker wanted

Answer (score 0):

Create a grid, with (for example): flexbox.

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: green;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">yada</div>
    <div class="column">yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yadaaaa oh dear this might even be two lines</div>
    <div class="column">even more yada! but with some extra line stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131"></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yadaaaa oh dear this might even be two lines</div>
    <div class="column">even more yada! but with some extra line stuff</div>
    <div class="column">yada</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this structure, each row's height is set by the highest column in the row, regardless of the content. This instead of forcing or fixing a height

Codepen image:
[image]

Comment: Those contents are now semantically disrupted. It shouldn't be in the HTML: three headers then three images and then three footers. It should be header,image,footer,header,image,footer,...

Comment: So please provide an 'undisrupted' version of the given question. Technically speaking- there is nothing wrong with the current HTML, OP has a question to a specific problem- and this is an answer to that problem.

Comment: Asker wanted cards (see question title). You don't have cards

Comment: You're free to disagree on the correct approach or semantic value of the answer, I prefer one that produces the desired result. Visual cards.

Comment: and poor SEO. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Some how I'm able to achieve [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma722/pxmk2rjh/21/)

but still I gave static height to footer, which I don't wanted to give. but this is fixing my problem, but if someone having better solution with out fixed footer height, will appreciated.

this is something where I can't change the structure so please fallow the link I shared.

I updated code with below properties

```
.header {
    flex: 1;
}
.footer {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While we are waiting for the CSS Grid Layout Level 2 specification to be set, we can only help ourselves with `display: contents`. For the browser which don't support that (IE, Edge) we will have a graceful degradation with `display: flex`.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 8px;
}
.grid .card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 16px);
}
@media (min-width: 641px) {
  .grid .card {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 16px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 961px) {
  .grid .card {
    flex-basis: calc(33% - 16px);
  }
}
.grid .card .header,
.grid .card .footer {
  height: auto;
}
.grid .card .content {
  height: 100%;
}

@supports (display: contents) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column dense;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 641px) {
    .grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 961px) {
    .grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
  }
  .grid .card {
    grid-row-end: span 3;
    display: contents;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    grid-column-start: 1;
  }
  .grid .card .header,
  .grid .card .content,
  .grid .card .footer {
    grid-column-start: 1;
  }
  @media (min-width: 641px) {
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+1) {
      grid-column-start: 1;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+1) .header,
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+1) .content,
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+1) .footer {
      grid-column-start: 1;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+2) {
      grid-column-start: 2;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+2) .header,
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+2) .content,
    .grid .card:nth-child(2n+2) .footer {
      grid-column-start: 2;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 961px) {
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+1) {
      grid-column-start: 1;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+1) .header,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+1) .content,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+1) .footer {
      grid-column-start: 1;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+2) {
      grid-column-start: 2;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+2) .header,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+2) .content,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+2) .footer {
      grid-column-start: 2;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+3) {
      grid-column-start: 3;
    }
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+3) .header,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+3) .content,
    .grid .card:nth-child(3n+3) .footer {
      grid-column-start: 3;
    }
  }
  .grid .card .header,
  .grid .card .content,
  .grid .card .footer {
    margin-left: inherit;
    margin-right: inherit;
    border-left: inherit;
    border-right: inherit;
  }
  .grid .card .header {
    margin-top: inherit;
    border-top: inherit;
  }
  .grid .card .footer {
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    border-bottom: inherit;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  padding: 16px;
}

.header {
  background-color: gold;
}

.content {
  background-color: silver;
}

.footer {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, earum.</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium dolor, magnam provident voluptatibus eius magni animi repellat sit molestiae labore voluptatum aperiam pariatur, ex quibusdam laborum porro quaerat! Reiciendis deleniti debitis quasi voluptatem aliquid odit quam quisquam earum? Dolore, voluptates.</div>
    <div class="footer">01</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Deserunt vero alias explicabo!</div>
    <div class="content">Explicabo voluptatem veniam voluptatibus, eum dolorum aliquam eligendi maxime at dicta voluptate? Maxime, amet dolorem reprehenderit debitis id dolore voluptates aperiam ea aut culpa dolor quas quam hic voluptas quae eum at. Harum hic, adipisci ipsum neque repellat unde at!</div>
    <div class="footer">02 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, fugit!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Nobis beatae incidunt explicabo!</div>
    <div class="content">Veritatis, sapiente? Optio totam nemo ut, ullam quaerat alias quisquam inventore placeat odio in tempore numquam aliquam quas repudiandae voluptatibus excepturi velit vel ducimus deleniti impedit expedita animi deserunt facilis nulla? Eos dignissimos corporis perspiciatis ducimus cupiditate excepturi, doloremque doloribus!</div>
    <div class="footer">03</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Dicta, similique. Incidunt, illum?</div>
    <div class="content">Sed quod vitae earum voluptas perspiciatis minima ipsa molestiae incidunt. Perferendis fuga accusamus ut sit suscipit, atque quasi eveniet, animi reiciendis quibusdam eum nulla, veniam sunt! Nihil, quis iusto! Molestias rerum incidunt dolor unde magni ab iusto dolores sed. Corrupti.</div>
    <div class="footer">04</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Sit, animi! Animi, sint?</div>
    <div class="content">Distinctio nihil voluptatibus perspiciatis deserunt amet voluptate ratione voluptatem. Rerum consectetur delectus autem nam dolores explicabo sequi, pariatur nostrum id sunt?</div>
    <div class="footer">05</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia excepturi optio odit asperiores eaque praesentium amet consequuntur non. Excepturi, dolorum!</div>
    <div class="content">Repudiandae ut reiciendis dolores? Porro neque minima, modi illo nam perspiciatis quae necessitatibus, dolorum sunt, fuga atque assumenda dolores nulla nesciunt tempora!</div>
    <div class="footer">06</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Iure assumenda accusantium perspiciatis?</div>
    <div class="content">Iste expedita et sequi voluptatum iusto dolorem numquam autem qui voluptas sapiente impedit, molestiae dicta deleniti ratione nostrum quae quas cumque veritatis ad eveniet cum dolor excepturi! Neque assumenda tempore minus quae accusamus! Suscipit at autem eaque quisquam dignissimos recusandae.</div>
    <div class="footer">07</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Natus, quisquam molestiae? Cupiditate.</div>
    <div class="content">Cumque totam qui, veritatis iste vitae veniam culpa maiores quam obcaecati! Ab consequatur quam maxime officia, itaque aut nesciunt magni velit delectus id eligendi temporibus voluptatem saepe officiis vitae asperiores fuga laboriosam! Similique alias vitae quis iure delectus, amet expedita?</div>
    <div class="footer">08</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Impedit tenetur cum saepe!</div>
    <div class="content">Consequuntur cumque debitis quasi id alias et officia fuga perspiciatis ratione cum accusantium delectus dicta itaque officiis illo quam sapiente ducimus quia reiciendis sunt, magnam numquam quae! Vitae dolorum sit autem ut, necessitatibus cumque neque aspernatur eos, ratione similique commodi!</div>
    <div class="footer">09</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Repellendus dolorum veniam consequuntur?</div>
    <div class="content">Doloribus autem harum, quibusdam aliquid ex eum animi recusandae id, soluta earum provident officiis ea? Consequuntur perspiciatis libero iusto deserunt tempore? Inventore explicabo eos repudiandae laudantium commodi ad maxime tempore in expedita iste tempora est exercitationem eveniet fugiat, cupiditate ex!</div>
    <div class="footer">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header">Nemo quia impedit eum?</div>
    <div class="content">Omnis recusandae qui debitis molestias illum nesciunt nostrum, vitae nihil, natus provident distinctio nulla aut non voluptate molestiae ipsum libero quasi unde eius eum. Nobis in dignissimos quos enim est iste quia voluptatum aperiam, beatae itaque ab cupiditate exercitationem ut!</div>
    <div class="footer">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```